# Using re.findall to match a string in html

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to use `re.findall()` to match instances of business names from a review website. For example, I'd like to capture names in a list like the ones in the example below:

```
website_html = ', Jimmy Bob's Tune & Lube, Allen's Bar & Grill, Joanne's - Restaurant,'
name_list = re.findall('[,]\s*([\w\'&]*\s?)*[,]', website_html)
```

My code isn't catching any patterns. Any ideas?

Comment: You should run `html.unescape(website_html)` first, that would simplify your input and regex, and make it easier to troubleshoot as well.

Comment: While it does not answer your question, you could consider [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) which is _a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and XML files_.

Comment: Thank you, I ran html.unescape on the website_html. I've adjusted my regex, but still not finding any matches.

Answer (score 1):

You only provided one input example, so this answer is based on your question as is:

```
# I replace the single quotes at the start and end of your input, because 
# Bob's throws a SyntaxError: invalid syntax
# 
website_html = ", Jimmy Bob's Tune & Lube,"

# I removed re.findall, because you only had one example so re.search or 
# re.match works.  
name_list = re.search(r'[,]\s*([\w\'&]*\s?)*[,]', website_html)

print (name_list.group(0))
# output
, Jimmy Bob's Tune & Lube,
```

If you have additional input values in website_html please provide them, so that I can modified my answer.

Here is the version that uses re.findall.

```
# I replace the single quotes at the start and end of your input, because 
# Bob's throws a SyntaxError: invalid syntax
# 
website_html = ", Jimmy Bob's Tune & Lube,"

# I wrapped your pattern as a capture group
name_list = re.findall(r'([,]\s*([\w\'&]*\s?)*[,])', website_html)

print (type(name_list))
# output 
<class 'list'>

print (name_list)
# output 
[(", Jimmy Bob's Tune & Lube,", '')]
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

This answer is based on the modified input to your original question.

```
website_html = ", Jimmy Bob's Tune & Lube, Allen's Bar & Grill, Joanne's - Restaurant,"
name_list = re.findall(r'[?:,].*[?:,]', website_html)
for item in name_list:
  split_strings = (str(item).split(','))
  for string in split_strings:
     print (string)

     # output 
     Jimmy Bob's Tune & Lube
     Allen's Bar & Grill
     Joanne's - Restaurant
```

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful. I tried to run re.findall() and wasn't able to make it work. I assume that's because there is only one example to return. I added a few more examples to the list (edit), and tried running it, but still not having any luck. Why would it work for re.search(), but not for re.findall()? Can I not just try: print(name_list) after using re.findall()?

Comment: I have modified my answer to fit your input modification.  If you have any additional questions concerning these answers please let me know.  If not, please accept the answer as solving your original question.